# Will current Windows Phone 8.1 apps run on Windows 10 Mobile devices whitout any code modifications?

Tags: windows-phone-8, compatibility, windows-10-mobile

Currently I have wp8 applications running on windows 10 mobile devices, but I am getting some unexpected results, specially with photo related tasks.

This is what is not working well:

```
//Initializations for photo chooser task 
PhotoChooserTask photoChooserTask = new PhotoChooserTask(); 
photoChooserTask.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(photoChooserTask_Completed);
...

//Starting the photo chooser 
photoChooserTask.Show();
...

//Getting result from photo chooser 
void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
   String photoPath = e.OriginalFileName;
}
```

This works well in an wp8 app installed on windows phone 8.1 device, getting always something like:

```
photoPath = "C:\Data\Users\Public\Pictures\Camera Roll\WP_20170504_002.jpg"
```

But has unexpected behavior in the same wp8 app installed on windows 10 device, sometimes getting something like:

```
photoPath = "C:\Data\Users\Public\Pictures\Camera Roll\WP_20170504_002.jpg"
```

But other times I get the following in the same device:

```
photoPath = "C:\Data\Users\DefApps\AppData\{82D0A9BD-6D54-4321-880B-445007A2A1B4}\local\PlatformData\PhotoChooser-b001485c-f41b-4676-b655-7aacee3d8267.jpg"
//This is not the real name of the saved photo, then is going to be a big problem if you want to save the name into a database an later use it to read the photo again.
```

I am testing this in the following devices:
Nokia Lumia 520 (windows phone 8.1 operating system)
Microsoft Lumia 550 (windows 10 mobile operating system)

Comment: same here. but your question is too broad to get any good answers. or just plain "no" in reply to the title. I'd suggest to post photo-related code that works on 8.1 and malfunctions on 10.

Comment: this is offtopic "too broad". Post the real issue that you have and code snippets with exceptions you get

Comment: ok, read the edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd think this is by design. In [Data for Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff402541(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_Localfolder), we can find **PlatformData** is one of **Special-use folders in the local folder**:

> This folder is created when your app uses the photo chooser task. For more info, see [**How to use the photo chooser task for Windows Phone 8**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394019(v=vs.105).aspx).

And in [How to use the photo chooser task for Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394019(v=vs.105).aspx), it declared that

> If an app that targets Windows Phone OS 7.1 is deployed to a phone running Windows Phone 8 and that app uses the photo chooser task, the system will create a directory in the top level of the app’s isolated storage called "PlatformData".

What happens in your scenario is similar, the system automatically creates "PlatformData" folder when your Windows Phone 8 app is deployed to Windows 10 Mobile.

As this is controlled by system, I'm afraid there is no workaround for this. If your app is a Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 app, I'd suggest using a [**file picker**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn642086(v=vs.105).aspx) instead of **photo chooser task**. Or you can port your app to Windows 10 like [Move from Windows Phone Silverlight to UWP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/wpsl-to-uwp-root).

Comment: I have solved my problem using a similar solution to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6032964/1491726

Comment: @adrian4aes Glad to know you've solved this issue. ;)